# How is in-class static const initialization of float different from int in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point

I have a class with `static const` members that I'm initializing inside the class declaration:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
        static const int i = 9;
        static const float f = 2.9999;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Foo::i << std::endl;
    std::cout << Foo::f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with GCC 4.8.2 with option `--std=c++11`, it gives this compile error:

```
foo.cpp:7:32: error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization of static data member ‘const float Foo::f’ of non-integral type [-fpermissive]
         static const float f = 2.9999;
                                ^
```

As the message indicates, the error goes away if the line is changed to `static constexpr float f = 2.9999;`.

Why should the in-class static const initialization of a floating-point variable be any different from a integral variable? Aren't they both just a value of certain size (number of bytes) that is copied over (like a macro) or referred to using a pointer?

Some older answers to similar (not the same) questions on SO indicate that this is because floating point expressions might give different results between the compiled machine and the execution machine (assuming a cross-compilation scenario).

However:

1. the above code assigns a value directly, there is no arithmetic operation that needs to be performed to compute a value
2. there might be different results for integral expressions too since its underflow and overflow results are not unambiguously defined across different architectures.
3. Finally, what magic does `constexpr` do here that `const` does not? Why doesn't the language just do what `constexpr` does when `const` is used? I mean, why another keyword when the following statements work fine as C++ code outside a class anyway:

   `const int i = 9;
   const float f = 2.9999;`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why, but before C++11, it only worked for integral types. C++11 allowed any literal type via `constexpr`.

Comment: @chris: Why doesn't C++11 just do whatever constexpr does for this statement and do it for const itself? Why require user to use a new keyword?

Comment: Have you tried `static const float f = 2.9999f`?

Comment: @barakmanos: Tried it. Same error message.

Comment: The standard doesn't seem to allude to any reason why. Both can be used in constant expressions, and both require the initializer to be a constant expression. The only difference seems to be that `constexpr` does all literal types. Maybe someone decided that requiring `constexpr` would make the code more clear and distinct from older code.

Comment: FWIW, I took a look at the `constexpr` proposal ([N2235](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf)) and it had this: http://i.imgur.com/QdaqXTN.png

Comment: Why the `emacs` tag? What does this question have to do with Emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a limitation of the language, and one that has been addressed by the introduction of generalized constant expressions.

Since the original C++, only static class member constants of integral type can be initialized inline; this is the is same type restriction as for non-type template parameters. So you can combine the two like this:

```
struct MyTrait { static const int value = 10; };

template <int N> struct Foo;

Foo<MyTrait::value> foo;
```

In this usage, the static constant is not odr-used and no definition is required. I'm speculating, but I can imagine that this kind of use was the primary intention of allowing inline initialization. For all other types, you would presumably want to have a definition anyway, so you might as well put the initializer in the definition.

This isn't an excuse, of course, and I suppose the introduction of `constexpr` seeks to rectify this original narrow-mindedness.

Comment: In the original C++, no static class members could be initialized inline.  That's an innovation of C++98.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I count that as "original" :-)

Comment: I'd been programming in C++ almost 10 years before that.  The first wide spread specification would be the first _The C++ Programming Language_, in 1985.